# How can i make this mysql query more efficient and run faster?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, time, time-complexity

This is my mysql query ( 3 Nested Select statements ) :

```
SELECT * FROM emotions 
WHERE 
( randomid IN 
     ( 
           SELECT idpost 
           FROM p_n_relation 
           WHERE idnetwork IN 
           (
                 SELECT id 
                 FROM networks 
                 WHERE name = 'Babblenow' 
                       AND isActive = 1 
                       AND isDeleted = 0
          ) 
       AND isActive = 1 AND isDeleted = 0 
   )   AND isActive = 1 
       AND isDeleted =0 
       AND onid = '0' AND type = 0 
)ORDER BY rating DESC
```

Each table emotions, p_n_relations and networks contain around 10k rows. 
This query takes more than 30 seconds to execute and hangs the server as it runs!
Can there be any more efficient way to do what i am trying to do? How do large companies manage to do this in seconds?

EDIT -
To be EXACT :
No. of rows in `p_n_relations : 5774` , `networks : 9`, `emotions : 427`
And this `Query took 125.6770 sec`.

My DB structure : 
Emotions Table, Network Table , P_n_relation table in order. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFJVh.jpg

Comment: Did you try the EXPLAIN statement in MySQL?

Comment: What is your MySQL version? Because subqueries are very buggy in MySQL < 6.0. Try to avoid them.

Comment: No sorry i have never heard about it!

Comment: @Fenistil Newest Version is 5.6.22 (Beta 5.7.5), so... where do I get MySQL 6.0?

Comment: Stop using sub select and start using JOINS for a starter too.

Comment: How can i use JOIN statements for this query? They are a bit Complicated thou.

Comment: Also use parameter binding rather than directly inserting values (`'Babblenow'`) into the SQL. Doing this is both a performance and security concern.

Comment: @Fenistil: I personally doubt that 6 really fixes it, I remember people saying the same about 4.2 versus 4.1, the mysql query planner just lacks some intelligence for these type of queries.

Comment: I write 6.0 from my mind, maybe I remember it wrong, but some times ago I read somewhere that would finally fix it :D We all hope, I think...

Comment: I don't see u_n_relations in your query, but there is a networks table.. And with good indexing, joining them can't be a problem. These are very small tables.

Comment: I see your tables data are rather small, Seems something's wrong even with this nested query. Have you checked the query_cache_limit and query_cache_size?

Comment: How can i check that?

Comment: @pendrive even i think so. It should not take more then 0.001 sec. But what's the probem?

Comment: @jackkorbin lets check out some of those configured values for mysql.

Comment: SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_query_cache'; SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'query_cache_size'; SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'query_cache_limit';

Comment: and also these two: SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sort_buffer_size'; SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'tmp_table_size';

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
SELECT emotions.* FROM emotions
LEFT JOIN p_n_relation ON (p_n_relation.idpost = emotions.randomid)
LEFT JOIN networks ON (networks.id = p_n_relation.idnetwork)
WHERE 
(networks.name='Babblenow') AND (networks.isActive = 1) AND (networks.isDeleted = 0) AND
(p_n_relation.isActive = 1) AND (p_n_relation.isDeleted = 0) AND
(emotions.isActive = 1) AND (emotions.isDeleted = 0) AND (emotions.onid = '0') AND (emotions.type = 0)
ORDER BY emotions.rating DESC
```

Based on the table structures you have posted I suggest to use the same field type for emotions.randomid and p_n_relation.idpost (now varchar(40) and varchar(50)). Beside that put indicies on emotions.randomid, p_n_relation.idpost, networks.id and p_n_relation.idnetwork. As the others suggested try to make index also on networks.name. After that, try to build your query step-by-step.

First, select emotions.* from emotions but don't use where and measure the time. It should fast, if isn't there is some great problem with your MySQL config.

```
SELECT emotions.* FROM emotions;
```

If it fast, join p_n_relation on it, but don't use where.

```
SELECT emotions.*, p_n_relation.* FROM emotions
LEFT JOIN p_n_relation ON (p_n_relation.idpost = emotions.randomid);
```

It should also fast if you have the right index. If not, try to EXPLAIN it:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT emotions.*, p_n_relation.* FROM emotions
LEFT JOIN p_n_relation ON (p_n_relation.idpost = emotions.randomid);
```

You can read [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain-output.html) about the EXPLAIN output, but you can also post it to your question.

So if it still fast, join the 3rd table on it:

```
SELECT emotions.*, p_n_relation.* FROM emotions
LEFT JOIN p_n_relation ON (p_n_relation.idpost = emotions.randomid)
LEFT JOIN networks ON (networks.id = p_n_relation.idnetwork);
```

Test, measure, then start to include the WHERE section step-by-step. If somewhere the performance dropped, you should investigate it (maybe a wrong or missing index, field type, or something with the MySQL itself can cause the problem).

Comment: To be Accurate , This Query took 28.5680 sec as measured by PhpMyadmin.

Comment: To give better answers, we need all the table structures, indexes and exactly what you want to get. I can join 600K+ rows tables here on a Core2Duo within 1-2 secs. It depends only on the data structure and good indexing.

Comment: That's amazing! How can i provide you with my Database structure?

Comment: SQL Dump the structure? Phpmyadmin / Open the table / Export tab / export the structure.

Or you can ScreenShot it, then upload the images somewhere, then link them here.

Comment: also in general, adding indexes to fields in where clauses (isActive, isDeleted ...) increases the performance.

Comment: @pendrive: He would get more bang for his buck by adding indices to columns with higher cardinality. I suggest first adding an index on `networks.name` column, then only adding to the boolean columns if necessary.

Comment: @MikePurcell actually I think its a little tricky to choose the best index. In mysql the shorter indexes are always faster and also the more fields get repeated in a query, the more preferable to be chosen as the first index. the networks.name appears only once here and probably a varchar of any number. Also its always advised to index just some prefix of a string column instead of indexing whole. Besides, in the above comment, I meant just to make a note on indexing on the where clause fields and did not hint to index which one first.

Comment: @Fenistil Why have you used LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN?

Comment: @jackkorbin Because this way if some row didn't have a pair in the second table, it's shown but with NULL values from the second table. I don't know exactly the full data-structure, we don't know if every row has a pair or not, and he needed it or not. If everything is related, then INNER can be used also.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to a join, inverting the join order:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.*
FROM networks n
JOIN p_n_relation r ON r.idnetwork = n.id
JOIN emotions e ON e.randomid = r.idpost
WHERE n.name = 'Babblenow' 
AND n.isActive = 1 
AND n.isDeleted = 0
```

This table order is optimal because your criteria is all on the network table. The optimizer is *supposed* to recognise this and change the join order automatically, but I have found through experience that optimizer s can be dense.

Create indexes (if they don't already exist):

```
create index networks_name on networks(name);
create index  p_n_relation_idnetwork on (p_n_relation(idnetwork);
```